# Как с помощью python написать API который будет работать на VPS сервере?

Tags: python, api

Можно ли с помощью python написать некий код API, который будет работать на VPS сервере и также к которому может обращаться пользователь, зная определенный ключ и отправив его c другого региона и компьютера?

Я понимаю, что нужно будет обрабатывать данные и прочее, мне необходимо объяснение того, что нужно использовать для создания такого кода и методов / функций с помощью которых другой пользователь сможет отправлять запросы.

Как это можно реализовать? Без создания сайта.

Comment: Ну, как реализовать?... Руками. Создаете на сервере скрипт(ы), который(е) будет(ут) слушать запросы к этому серверу извне и или изнутри, разбирать эти запросы и выполнять указания из них. Технологии, протоколы и прочее сильно зависят от того, что вы хотите делать. На сегодня в вебе наиболее распространенными, протоколами например, есть http(s) для сайтов и веб-приложений, ftp -для файлов, smtp - для почты.

Comment: @Zombotron 3% полезной информации. Почему? - мне необходимо объяснение того, что нужно использовать для создания такого кода и методов / функций

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой и комментарий к нему. "скажите, где и как приобрести предмет, но чтобы не идти за ним пешком?" - вот ваша просьба. )))

Comment: Нужны руки и конкретные хотелки хотя бы для начала. Почему впс, а не юкоз или гуглотаблицы, почему именно апи, а не тупо бд где-то далеко и приложение, которое буде раз в день эту бд выкачивать, а потрошить самостоятельно на клиенте. Почему не на своем локальном компе или старом телефоне/планшете, а на впс. И еще куча этих ""пачиму""...